# Bison reads semantic values of char * symbols until the end of rule

Tags: bison, semantics, flex-lexer

Can anyone help me with these simple problem. I have these tiny grammar rules in Bison:

```
pair_list
 : pair_list pair               
 | pair                         
; 

pair
 : KEY ':' VAR ';'          { $$ = new_sym($1, $3); add_entry($$);}
;
```

I have these type declarations:

```
%union {
    struct symbol *symbl;
    char *key;
    int val;
    int token;
}

%token <key> KEY
%token <val> VAL
%token <token> EOL

%type <symbl> pair
%type <key> id
```

My problem is that the value Bison assigns to `$1` is the string value of the rule from '$1' up to the end of the rule. For example, if the Flex returned `"hello"` for `KEY` and `23` for `VAL`, the value of `$1` becomes `"hello:23;"`. How can I make bison make `$1` to be just `"hello"`?

Here are my flex rules:

```
[ \t\n]+                {/*Ignore*/}
[0-9]+                  {yylval.val = atoi(yytext); return VAL;}
":"                     {return ':';}
";"                     {return ';';}
[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*   {yylval.key = yytext; return KEY;}
```

To prove that Flex rules are correct I edited my grammar:

```
/*Edited grammar to show that yylex returns correct value yylval.key for KEY which is assigned to    id. However, when evaluated in rule pair: KEY ':' VAR ';', the value of $1 became the string representation of KEY + ":" + VAR + ";" (where + is for concatenation).
*/
pair_list
 : pair_list pair               
 | pair                         
; 

pair
 : id ':' VAR ';'           { $$ = new_sym($1, $3); add_entry($$);}
;

id
 : KEY                      {printf("%s\n", $1); /*This prints the id correctly*/}
;
```

Comment: There's (probably) nothing wrong with your Bison rules, it's the Flex rules and code that is the most likely problem. Run the lexer separately to see what it outputs, and please edit the question to include the relevant part of the Flex file.

Comment: I already tested my Flex rules and it captures the correct tokens.

Comment: And did you check the semantic values returned by the lexer as well (i.e. checked the data in `yylval`) for the tokens?

Comment: Yes, I checked everything that Flex do and it is fine. In my theory, think the problem is that Bison assigns string to $1 from KEY until it reaches the end-of-rule, may be because it is looking for a null character.

Comment: One last (hopefully) request, can you please show how you check what `$1` is? Do you e.g. print it in the `new_sym` function? Oh, and what is `$3`?

Comment: I already added the grammar I used for checking `$1`, (please refer to the second set of grammar rules). Also, `$3` is for `VAL`.

Comment: So in the second grammar it's wrong in the rule for `pair` but right in the rule for `id`? And I simply wanted to know if `$3` is what you expect it to be or not, since it's seems to be squashed in with `$1` in the rule for `pair`.

Comment: Your right, it is correct in the rule of `id` but not in the rule of `pair` that's why I think (but with no proof) that because the type of `KEY` is `char *` taking its characters from a file, Bison has no way of telling when to stop assigning characters to `$1` and decided to read until the end of the rule. My explanation is funny, I know.

Comment: To test if $3 is the culprit, I tried to change the rule of `pair` to `VAL ':' KEY EOL` where EOL is a lexer token `\n+`. After doing this, the value of `$3` (formerly '$1' because of the change in arrangements) became `KEY` + `EOL` (where + is for concatenation). Again, Bison reads until the end of the rule.

Comment: I solved the problem (or I think I did). First of all, I'm trying to build a mini-foundation of a symbol table here. I have data structure `struct` with a member `char *key` where the `KEY` will be placed (used for hash table). Because of the funny theory I have, I changed the data type of the member `key` to `char key[32]` to force Bison or C to put a null character in the end of the `key`. This way, Bison will no longer attempt to look for a null character crazily (bcoz it looks for it until the end of the rule).

Comment: I think this is also the reason why C and C++ variable names can be of any length, but the first 31 characters are only significant.

Comment: You cannot just pass `yytext` to `bison`. You *must* make a copy. See the links in the answer to the duplicate question.